# MongoDB takes long for indexing

Tags: mongodb, performance, indexing, nosql

I have the following setup:

- Mac Pro with 2 GB of RAM (yes, not that much)
- MongoDB 1.1.3 64-bit
- 8 million entries in a single collection
- index for one field (integer) wanted

Calling `.ensureIndex(...)` takes more than an hour, actually I killed the process after that. My impression is, that it takes far too long. Also, I terminated the process but the index can be seen with `.getIndexes()` afterwards.

Anybody knows what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Adding an index on an existing data set is expected to take a while, as the entire BTree needs to be constructed. If you think this is taking an unreasonable amount of time, or you've seen a regression in performance the best bet is to ask about it on [the list](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/).

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to point out the command:

```
db.currentOp()
```

which prints the current operations running on the server, and also shows the indexing process.

The foreground indexing is done in 3 steps, and the background one in 2 steps (if I remember correctly), but the background one is alot slower. The foreground one on the other hand locks the collection while indexing it (ie not very useful on a running application server).

As said before, google BTree if you are interested in how they work.

> Anybody knows what is going wrong here?

Are you running via ssh or connecting remotely in some way? Sound a bit like a broken pipe issue. Did you create the index with {background : true} or not?